# Custom icon in timestempedgeojson folium?

Tags: python, json, icons, folium

i'm writing to know how i could set a custom icon within timestempedgeojson plugin inside folium. I would to know two things:

1. If it is possible to hide a marker in the last point of a street in the timestempedgeojson plugin;
2. How i could use a custom icon with this type of plugin.
   I cannot find a detailed guide to find a solution to my problem, only some examples. I'm going to share my code and I'd be very grateful if you could give me support.

I tried to do in this way.
Here is my code:

```py
map = folium.Map(
    location = [portici_gdf.centroid.y, portici_gdf.centroid.x],
    tiles='cartodbpositron',
    zoom_start= 15
)
folium.GeoJson(portici_gdf, style_function= lambda x: {'fillcolor':'blue'}).add_to(map)
```

Here the part to add the timestampgeojson plugin>

```py
lines = [
    {
        'coordinates': f(gdf_f.loc['Piazza San Pasquale']['line']),
        'dates':['2023-03-31T10:00:00']*len(f(gdf_f.loc['Piazza San Pasquale']['line'])),
        'color': 'red',
    },

]

features = [
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': line['coordinates']
        },
        'properties': {
            'times': line['dates'],
            'icon': 'test',
            'iconstyle': {
                'iconUrl': "./data/test.png",
            },
            'style': {
                'color':line['color'],
            }
        }
    }
    for line in lines
]

TimestampedGeoJson(
    {
        'type':'FeatureCollection',
        'features': features,
    },
    period='PT5M',
    add_last_point=False,
).add_to(map)
```

The function f in the first line of the second script and the two dataframe above gdf_f and portici_gdf appear as follow:

```py
def f(frame):
    xy = frame.xy
    longs = xy[0].tolist()
    lats = xy[1].tolist()
    return [list(z) for z in zip(longs, lats)]

portici_gdf = ox.geocode_to_gdf("Portici, Italy")
gdf_f = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry='geometry')
```

The df dataframe appears as a dataframe with some Multinistring of each steet and some centroid coordinates.

Thank you for your time and i wih you a good day.

Comment: Can you include `gdf_f` and `portici_gdf` (or a subset) in your question?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. I forgot. I'm going to update my question. Thanks @OriYarden